# How do I grep a word after a match if positive lookbehind does not work?

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep the word that comes after the match "name:"

```
Her name: Ana Frost. I know we are meant to be.
Her name: Beth Cooper. I know we are meant to be.
```

I want my output to be:

```
Ana
Beth
```

I tried using the command below but it didn't work:

```
grep -i '(?<=name:\s)\w+'
```

Is there a way to do this without the positive lookbehind or make the Unix shell somehow recognize it?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to tell grep to use Perl-compatible regular expressions with the `-P` option.

Comment: This might help: `grep -Po '(?<=name: )[^ ]*' file`

Comment: All of the answers helped very much. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason to use any lookbehind. Just find the word after `name:`.

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/.*name: \([A-Z][a-z]\+\).*/\1/'
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
sed 's/.*name: \([A-Z][a-z]\{1,\}\).*/\1/'
```

With `grep` with perl regex:

```
grep -Po 'name: \K\w+'
```

Comment: Under Mac OSX there is no grep with perl regex and the sed "\+" escape does not work. So as an alternate for OSX write: sed 's/.*name: \([A-Z][a-z]\{1,\}\).*/\1/'

Comment: What does the \K stand for?

Comment: `-o` prints the matched pattern. `\K` is part of perl regex, it "clears" the current matching pattern/buffer. So `grep 'name: \w+'` would print `name: Ana`. The `\K` "clears" the `name:` part from matchin pattern, making `grep` printing only Ana. It's commonly used like `grep -Po 'something \Koutput this'`

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful!